# How can I view AIDE warnings?

Tags: android, aide-ide, android-ide

In the Android development app **AIDE**, how can I view the compiler warning messages? Previous versions displayed a yellow squiggly underline, which you could tap and a toast message would pop up. However, this doesn't happen any more.

For errors there is an *Error List* panel, but that is only for the red squiggly underlines.

Is there something similar for warnings?

Comment: Update: you can now long-press a yellow (or red) warning squiggle to see the message pop up in a toast. This probably came in around version 3.1 or 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any option to enable a Warning list panel.

I tried to generate a warning by deleting `@Override` in a basic `onCreate()` method and there was no indication in the *Settings*, *Errors* or *Debugger* tab.

Note: I have also sent an email to the developers and there was no response yet. Unfortunately you might consider choosing another IDE if you want to fix your warnings.

**Later Edit** - The official response from ***Appfour Team***:

> Sorry, but there is no "view" specifically for warnings.  You can
>   (right/left-)swipe through all views to see all possible
>   "view-panels". (Or check in menu: view)
>
> Trixi
>
> Appfour Support Team
>  For more information and additional help please
>   visit:
>  AIDE forum
>  AIDE community on Google+
>  WIB community on Google+

Answer (score 1):

Usually people complain about warnings and try to suppress them with tag

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

Do you by the chance use this tag? It may prevent warnings.

Comment: You would first have to know what the warning is before being able to suppress it, which is the problem I've got. Anyway, I definitely do not want to suppress these warnings, I want to fix them properly like all good programmers should.